# create calculation in column on multiindex df

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

i have a below multiindex df, that need to converted to a df2 with additional columns based on some formula,

input df_1,

```
date    sku        supplier  a     a    a     a       a      b        b     b       b        b
                            a1     a2   a3    a4      a5     b1       b2    b3      b4      b5
1/1/2021    394031  14654    -     -  1,368   1,368   1,368   -       -   $49,864   $55,609      $876 
1/1/2021    394031  26944 (2,160)  -  (2,160) (2,160) 720    $(2,333) -   $(78,732) $(90,886)    $504
```

using these formula,

```
Formula,
a = value from a3
b6 = value from b3
b7 = b4 - b1
b8 = absolute value of b2 + b5
```

expected df_2,

```
date    sku        supplier    a      b6           b7       b8
1/1/2021    394031  14654    1,368   $49,864     $55,609     $876 
1/1/2021    394031  26944    (2,160)  $(78,732)  $(88,553)   $504
```

Comment: It is quite difficult to import dataframes with MultiIndexes from text, same with dataframes containing lists/tuples. Here you combine both! Please provide your data as dictionary: `df.to_dict()`

Comment: I imported the data using read_csv into a dataframe and the used the pivot_table function to create the pivot table (now this is df_1 in above example). My question is how to get df_2 using formula provided.. Hope this is helpful in assisting me...